# java client build error: apache.cassandra not found

Tags: client, cassandra

I am trying to build a java client to talk with cassandra, when i ant release, i got error that module not found org.apache.cassandra#apacke.cassandra;0.85

I have installed cassandra 0.85 and put dependeny in ivy.xml file as below

I have even tried to tell javac in build.xml the path of the jar such as

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean">
<mkdir dir="${build.dir.classes}"/>
<javac srcdir="${src.java.dir}"
destdir="${build.dir.classes}"
debug="${javac.debug}"
includeantruntime="false">
<classpath refid="test.classpath">
<pathelement path="/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-0.8.5.jar />
</classpath>
</javac></target>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

"module not found org.apache.cassandra#**apacke**.cassandra;0.85"

did you mean,

org.apache.cassandra#**apache**.cassandra;0.85